# Return all the cells from column B & C if the value in column A equals a certain value

Tags: google-sheets, database

Let's say we have the recipes of various cocktails stored in this format below. I would like to create a formula which will allow me to return a table with ingredients and volume of the selected cocktail only. Hope that makes sense.

| Cocktail | Ingredient | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Negroni | Gin | 33 |
| Negroni | Vermouth | 33 |
| Negroni | Campari | 33 |
| Margarita | Tequila | 40 |
| Margarita | Lime | 40 |
| Margarita | Triple Sec | 20 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got the above table in A1:C7, then the following would return a table of ingredients & volumes for a given cocktail:

```
=query(A1:C7,"select B,C where A='X'")
```

X is the chosen cocktail. The single quotes are required